# JQuery change event only firing once

Tags: jquery

I see this problem is common but cant seem to find a solution to my problem. The below code changes the selected items in dropdown B based on what is selected in dropdown A. This works fine the first time but subsequent changes are not registered. Any help would be appreciated.

```
$('select[name=LoanProduct]').on('change', function() 
    {   
        var SelectedLoanID = $(this).val();
        var SelectedLoanInterestRate = $('#LoanProduct option:selected').attr('interest_rate');
        var SelectedLoanDescription= $('#LoanProduct option:selected').text();

        $('#LoanReason option').each(function()
        {
            var associatedloanproductids = $(this).attr('loanproducts');
            var loanreasonallproducts = $(this).attr('allproducts');
            var loanreasonvalue = $(this).text();
            var associatedloanproductvalue = $(this).val();
            if (associatedloanproductids.indexOf(SelectedLoanID) == -1) 
            {
                $("#LoanReason option[value='" + associatedloanproductvalue + "']").remove();
            }
            if (loanreasonallproducts == "true")
            {
                $("#LoanReason").append("<option value='" + loanreasonvalue + "'>" + loanreasonvalue + "</option>");
            }
        });
        $("#LoanReason").prepend("<option value=''>Please select...</option>");
    });
```

EDIT

I get an error of

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
```

Comment: Have you get any error in console?

Comment: wrap this in $(document).ready(function(){ .... code here .... })

Comment: @user3385136 please provide html or prepare jsfiddle

Comment: Didnt realise I could check javascript errors but now I do! Error reads "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined"

Comment: check if SelectedLoanID value's is coming . it is coming undefined.

Comment: @Creator How do i go about checking the value?

Comment: Try using console.log() or alert for checking values . or create a fiddle so we can check .

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code with document on ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){ /*.... code here ....*/ })
```

Comment: Apologies already have it wrapped in $(document).ready(function(){}. Just didnt bring it into the code. Not the solution though as I wrapped this single function rather than a group and still only firing once.

Comment: Prepare a fiddle then . l